# php ajax post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do an ajax post request to the file called "sendMail.php". I have no clue what is wrong, I just can't see it.

the js works, it logs the value's from the inputs, in chrome dev tools I can see it is sent to the PHP file...
chrome dev tools screen
[image]

I'm a bit rusty, last PHP code was about a year ago.

below you'll find my PHP and js code.

folder tree(index.html is the main file where it is operated):

[image]

php:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   $requestbody = file_get_contents('php://input','r');
   $jsonbody = json_decode($requestbody, true);
   $action = $jsonbody['action'];

    switch($action){
        case "sendMail":
            $name = $requestbody->{'name'};
            $gsm = $requestbody->{'gsm'};
            $mail = $requestbody->{'mail'};
            $msg = $requestbody->{'msg'};
            $response = json_encode( '{"naam":"'.$name.'","gsm":"'.$gsm.'","mail":"'.$mail.'"}');
            echo $response;
            break;
    }
}else{
    http_response_code(405);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $response = '{"error":"request method is not allowed."}';
    echo($response);
}
?>
```

js:

```
function sendMail(){
    console.log(document.getElementById("mail_naam").value);
    console.log(document.getElementById("mail_gsm").value);
    console.log(document.getElementById("mail_mail").value);
    console.log(document.getElementById("mail_msg").value);
    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:'mail/sendMail.php',
        dataType:'json',
        data: {
            "action":"sendMail",
            "name":  document.getElementById("mail_naam").value,
            "gsm": document.getElementById("mail_gsm").value,
            "mail":document.getElementById("mail_mail").value,
            "msg": document.getElementById("mail_msg").value
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log("succes")
        console.log(data);
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(result)
    });
}
```

Comment: what's the output of console.log(data);?

Comment: nothing, doesn't reach the "done"

Comment: @Rp9 i added a screen of chrome devtools

Comment: are you using more than one echo in php file ?

Comment: yes, one in the case, and one in the else

Comment: try only one echo in php file hope that will work

Comment: what's the output of `print_r(file_get_contents("php://input"));` you don't need the `'r'` parameter. There is no `'r'` parameter for `file_get_contents` :)

Comment: this is the result, removing 'r' doesn't change a thing though...
action=sendMail&name=Achiel+Volckaert&gsm=smt&mail=smt&msg=azerzerzer

Comment: but jsonbody is empty so action is also empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added this, and this worked:

PHP

```
  if(empty($action) || $jsonbody){ $action = $_POST['action']; }

  switch ($action) {
      case "sendMail":    
          $name = $_POST["name"];
          $gsm =  $_POST['gsm'];
          $mail = $_POST['mail'];
          $msg =  $_POST['msg'];
          mailVraag($mail,$name,$msg);
          mailVraag("achiel@protoware.be","protoware",$msg . "tel:".$gsm ."email: ".$mail);

          $response = json_encode( '{"naam":"'.$name.'","gsm":"'.$gsm.'","mail":"'.$mail.'"}');
          echo $response;
          break;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `method` parameter in Ajax, so replace it with `type`.

**Try the below code:**

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'mail/sendMail.php',
        dataType:'json',
        data: {
            "action":"sendMail",
            "name":  document.getElementById("mail_naam").value,
            "gsm": document.getElementById("mail_gsm").value,
            "mail":document.getElementById("mail_mail").value,
            "msg": document.getElementById("mail_msg").value
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log("succes");
        console.log(data);
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: Ummm... `type` is just an alias for `method`...
Type: Prior to 1.9, Method: 1.9 and newer.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem is that `$requestbody`is always empty.
You should use `$_POST` instead, as source.

```
$requestbody = $_POST;
```

Kind of.

[php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) Good reference: [Description](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php#112032)

[jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)